# Required algebra level to read Royden's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I think nobody has ever asked the question I pose right now. I am very interested in reading Royden's *Real Analysis*, and I think it is required some modern algebra, does anybody know how much is exactly required to make it through this book?

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you will need to be familiar with vector spaces and linear transformations.

Comment: There is also a chapter on Lebesgue measure which talks about $\sigma-\text{algebras}$ so it's worth knowing what they are

Comment: @DanRobertson I honestly haven't dealt with $\sigma$ algebras outside of measure theory. Most measure theory texts will clearly define them.